# Create new file for each SVG path from unix command line

Tags: xml, unix, command-line, svg

How do I split SVG path shapes into new files using Unix command line tools (for example [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html))?

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg>
  <g>
    <path />
    <path />
    <path />
  </g>
</svg>
```

would turn into three files with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg>
  <g>
    <path />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Background: I need to render paths in SVG files independently from one another to .png (for this step, I intend using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) in the command line).